# display custom plugin view on front end inside template body

Tags: php

EDIT

May be my question is not well formed
i need to use the url http://localhost/wordpress/houses/all-houses
to display a house plugin view somewhere in plugin directory

```
function getHouses(){
     include plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'public/publicHouse.php';
}
```

the result i'm getting is on the picture below

[image]

I'm expecting the view with the whole template and houses view inside body template area

any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Frank P. Walentynowicz i dit it with fake post and it worked. on this link

[wordpress fake post](http://scott.sherrillmix.com/blog/blogger/creating-a-better-fake-post-with-a-wordpress-plugin/)

Answer (score 0):

In your plugin class (e.g. MyPlugin), add public static function, returning some content:

```
public static function my_plugin_output() {
    // Build your content
    $output = '<div>';
    $output .= 'This is a text to display.';
    $output .= '</div>';
    return $output;
}
```

Once your plugin is activated, add this line to any template, you want the plugin content to appear:

```
<?php if (class_exists('MyPlugin')) echo MyPlugin::my_plugin_output(); ?>
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without touching a template. suppose i create a plugin module that someone else without knowledge of programming can use in his website. i'm wondering how those plugins we use show their views without changing the template files

Comment: If you don't want to touch existing templates, read this article about fake post/pages creation - http://scott.sherrillmix.com/blog/blogger/creating-a-better-fake-post-with-a-wordpress-plugin/